# Could not load type 'namespace._default' after publishing to IIS server

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

After getting my app working . I published it to the *IIS* and got the following error :

```
Server Error in '/Library' Application.

Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'go._default'.

Source Error: 


Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="go._default" %>
Line 2:  
Line 3:  

Source File: /library/go/default.aspx    Line: 1 

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34009
```

How can I resolve this error? FYI: I only have filesystem access to this server. I published it from VS to the location `\\Servername\Library\go` .

**EDIT**: I forgot to mention that I did check the `bin` folder and it has three files in it, two .dlls for packages I added via nuget, and a `go.dll`.

Comment: Did you make sure all files were deployed properly?

Comment: Seems like your `bin` folder didn't get copied over.

Comment: I added some information about the `bin` folder to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was using a publishing to a sub-folder of a larger website, the bin files that were uploaded were being put in `\Library\go\bin`, but the server was looking for them in `\Library\bin`.

Creating a `\Library\bin` folder and copying the `.dlls` there resolved the problem. If someone would like to comment on how I can rewrite the path in the `Inherits=` to keep them in the `\Library\go\bin` folder, that would be appreciated.